# Hyper-V snapshot/checkpoint behavior with physical hard disk

Tags: windows-10, virtual-machine, hyper-v, snapshot

What is the behavior of the snapshot/checkpoint feature in Hyper-V when there are physical hard disks attached to the virtual machine? I have a virtual machine with four physical disks passed through to it and I'm wondering if I will be able to take a snapshot before I try to update the operating system, which resides on a separate VHDX.

Specifically, I am wondering if the standard checkpoint feature will even work, and if so will it create snapshot files for each physical hard disk or just ignore snapshots for them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using pass through disks, it is not possible to take a snapshot/checkpoint.  When you attempt to, it throws an error saying that the operation failed due to a pass through disk being present.

For that reason, I started making all of my disks VHDX.  For the ones that would have been pass through, I just make them fixed sized disks.

Comment: Well that sucks. The drives are cloned from another server, so it's going to be annoying if I need to try to convert them to vhdx every time I want to set them up on the Hyper-V system.

Comment: @user Yeah, I'm not sure why they never allowed for just the VHDX to be check-pointed, but my guess would be that they are afraid that this could cause inconsistent data.

Answer (score 5):

I got a checkpoint error "Cannot take checkpoint" related to having a physical disk attached to my machine.

It had nothing to do with VHD or VHDX virtual disks, I just had to go to my VM **Settings > Management > Checkpoints** and **turn Checkpoints off** to solve the problem.